# URL validation IsWellFormedUriString always return true

Tags: c#, url, uri

I'm using the following code to validate a url, but the problem that in both cases 
the check retruns true. How should I get false in the second option?

Here bool is true

```
 bool isWellFormedUriString = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://stackoverflow.com/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Here it is true as well

```
 bool isWellFormedUriString = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("ddddd", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

and now when I do 
`_uri = new Uri(_url);` I got exception ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string `ddddd` could be a valid "part" of a full URI, so using `Relative` or `RelativeOrAbsolute` returns true.

Try changing the second parameter to `UriKind.Absolute`:

```
bool isWellFormedUriString  // returns true
    = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://stackoverflow.com/", UriKind.Absolute);

bool isWellFormedUriString  // returns false
    = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("ddddd", UriKind.Absolute);
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Absolute URIs are characterized by a complete reference to the resource (example: http://www.contoso.com/index.html), while a relative Uri depends on a previously defined base URI (example: /index.html).

Comment: At the same time bool isWellFormedUriString = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://ddddd", UriKind.Absolute); will return true. Not sure if this is really a valid Url according to standards, but it makes this method pretty useless for checking internet urls.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Uri result;
if (Uri.TryCreate("http://stackoverflow.com",UriKind.Absolute, out result) && 
    result.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp) 
{
    //Use the valid Uri here
}
```

I restricted the valid schemes because otherwise even directories URIs would be valid (Ex: `c:\\directory\\filename` )